# Nginx добавить header к запросу до отправки его в php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, cookie, php-fpm

**Цель:** установить Cookies **до** того, как запрос будет отправлен в php-fpm.

Как я понимаю, такая строка устанавливает Cookies лишь для ответа уже **после** обработки запроса php-fpm:

`add_header Set-Cookie "KEY=VALUE";`

То, что я хочу, вообще возможно? Если да - то как, спасибо!

Comment: @DexterMorganov Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи директивы `fastcgi_param` FastCGI-серверу можно передать произвольные параметры, которые впоследствии FastCGI-сервер может обработать в качестве Cookie.

Источник: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html